# onRestore Purchase button code for phonegap/inAppPurchaseManager plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the InAppPurchaseManager plugin for phonegap I'm unsure how to get the restore purchases button code to work. I'm not even sure if this pluggin included all the proper code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the call. Just not sure what to do next.

window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onRestored = function(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt) {
                    console.log('restored: ' + productId);
                    /* See the developer guide for details of what to do with this */
                }

Answer (score 0):

Got it! All you have to do is add this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(".ftk50").click(function() {
      window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.restoreCompletedTransactions(); 
    });
</script>

<a href="#" class="ftk50">Restore All Purchases</a>
```

Comment: The day has come for an answer! I have created a new github for just this and many other questions! https://github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE